# SonarQube passing code that should fail

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube6.3

Using sonarqube-6.3.1 and sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778, I can run the command .sonar-scanner from the bin directory of the scanner folder. This outputs a bunch of stuff stating that it's loading and scanning.

I can view this on the SonarQube webpage and see the files I expect when I click the code tab for that project as I've configured it however. One file is proper code that compiles and has one expected bug as defined by the profile it states it's applying, the other file is just copy and paste of the non-compliant code smells.

The dashboard states there are no bug, vulnerabilities, code smells, or duplication. I'm struggling to figure out why it isn't detecting the errors i've intentionally put in.

Comment: You should first consider to upgrade to latest LTS (6.7) version of SonarQube

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam
I've updated to 6.7.1 and also updated c# plugins

It's still failing to find the errors in the files int's scanning, here is the command output from sonar-scanner -x
[Sonar Scanner Output](https://pastebin.com/cTcYARnQ)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your log but I'm not at all a C# expert. I'll let someone else help you on this issue.

Comment: Okay, thank you, The thing that stands out to me in the log is lines 80-89 stating missing requirements but no indication of what requirements.

Comment: Maybe you should update the title and the description, or open another thread to highlight issue you've found in the scanner log. Because I think that this thread is currently too "generic". For instance, I'm not sure that c# users will understand that this is a c# issue (I've added the tag but I dont' think it's enough).

Comment: I too having same issue. I'm using 6.7.1... Any luck?

Comment: According to my boss, .net is depreciated with the way we were using it. Had to follow the steps here using msbuild
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Scanning+on+Windows